# Virtual machine, container shared CPU on Cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, docker, virtual-machine, containers

Many cloud providers host instances with virtual machine or container.

Let's say I need 4 CPUs for my application and launch Google compute engine VM that has 4 CPUs. But it's virtual machine. Is that guaranteed that all 4 CPUs are exclusively available to my instance, or are those shared with other unknown virtual machines by somebody else located in the same physical machine in cloud provider?

Same in container, I need 4 CPUs for my application but run it under container. And let's say I run another copy of application in the same machine in another container runtime. Does that mean those two application would share the CPU powers, and might possibly slow down because of that? How would CPU resource allocation work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost always going to be sharing the underlying physical hardware with other virtual servers or containers in a cloud environment. A cloud provider should provide you with a baseline of CPU performance you can expect from the instance size you select.

I don't know if other cloud providers offer this, but AWS has the concepts of "[dedicated instances](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/purchasing-options/dedicated-instances/)" and "[dedicated hosts](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/dedicated-hosts/)" that might be useful to you if this is a real concern.

Answer (score 0):

1) [You get 4 Virtual CPUs, and 11 Google Compute Engine Units.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types) The underlying physical cores may or may not be shared.

2) If you have two containers running on the same machine, then yes the resources will be shared between the two containers. Whether it slows down or not is dependant on your app!